# Outputting HTML into a textbox

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to output HTML into a textbox and not have it break the textbox.

I'd like it so in the textbox I could have HTML in there, such as spans, h1s, h2s, etc. Each time I try do this the textbox breaks.

[image]

I've tried: stripslashes(), decoding the html and re-encoding it. I'm sure there's a simple function that does this but I can't seem to find it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You could try htmlentities($value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Seth suggests, you should use [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).

This way, a string like this:

```
$str = htmlentities("A 'quote' is <b>bold</b>");
```

Will be converted to this:

```
$str = "A 'quote' is &lt;b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt;";
```

When outputted to the page, it will show `&lt;` properly as `<`, etc.